# Analytical solution of 2nd order nonlinear ODE ($y''+(a+by^2)y'+cy = 0$)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nonlinear-optimization

I encountered the following ode in the attempt to solve the problem of nonlinear van der pol equation. I have tried for a long time to give it a solution but failed.

$y''+(a+by^2)y'+cy = 0$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ is a given constant, The problem is to solve y from this equation.

I was hoping that someone might be able to spot a clever transformation, or even argue that it is impossible to find any other explicit solutions. I would also be interested to know of any references where such a class of ode that might have been studied.

This also leads me to ask if there is any general theory known about when can a solution to an ode (say of second order) be expressed in terms of elementary functions, or is it just a case-by-case study? Thanks!

Comment: You can set $p=y'$, as a function of $y$, so that $y''=pp_y$ and $p_y+(a+by^2)+cy/p=0$. If you can solve this (this is certinly true if $c=0$), you get $p=p(y)$ and another first order ode appears.